# overlap buttons in div tag using css

Tags: html, css

hello just a quick question about overlapping two buttons with a div tag, how do i do it? i tried position and margin but both do not move the buttons.

heres the html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div style="margin:auto;">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-login">Log in</button>
    </div>
    <div class="signup-form">
    <label style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:20px">Create an Account</label>

    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-login">Sign Up Free</button>
    </div>
        <label style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:20px">or</label>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="social_media">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-facebook"></button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-gmail"></button>
    </div> 
</body>
```

heres the css:

```
.signup-form {
    top:-40px;
    position:relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 25px auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:400px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 2px #330000;
    z-index: -1;
}

.social_media {
    text-align:center;
}

.btn-facebook {
    margin-bottom:60px;
    padding-left:30px;
    background-image: url(fb.gif);
    background-color: #3b5998;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px grey;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
}

.btn-gmail {
    margin-bottom:60px;
    top:50%;
    padding-right:30px;
    background-image: url(g+.gif);
    background-color: #dc4a38;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px grey;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
}
```

also the first screenshot is what it looks like now and the second is from a photoshopped image on what im trying to replicate

[image: current look]

[image: photoshop]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding to the btn classes

position: absolute;

then move them to desired position
you may need to change the z index also.

Answer (score 2):

Set the position `property value` for the parent to `relative` (to control overlap) and that of the `button DIV` to `absolute`. Now  place your button inside the `button DIV`, then use `negative values` for `left`, `right`, `top` or `bottom` to position the `button DIV` where you want.

```css
.parent {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  background: darkOrange;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: -22.5px;
  left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

<div class="button">

  <input type="button" value="my button" />
  
</div>

<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the position on the `social_media` div to `relative` and then use the `top` property to move them as needed. For example:

```
.social_media {
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    top: -74px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1t0dmrL1/)**