# Put Button on Center Between Borders in CSS and MUI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I need to put the button on the center just like in the picture below.
It should be on the lines. What is the proper and correct way to do this?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-ptolemy-2mg3f8?file=/demo.js)

[image]

```
<MainContainer>
      <Stack spacing={1}>
        <Card sx={{ minWidth: 275 }}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography
              sx={{ fontSize: 14 }}
              color="text.secondary"
              gutterBottom
            >
              Word of the Day
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="h5" component="div">
              be{bull}nev{bull}o{bull}lent
            </Typography>
            <Typography sx={{ mb: 1.5 }} color="text.secondary">
              adjective
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2">
              well meaning and kindly.
              <br />
              {'"a benevolent smile"'}
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Stack>
      <Stack justifyContent={"center"} alignItems={"center"}>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" sx={{ maxWidth: 50 }}>
          Hello
        </Button>
      </Stack>
    </MainContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" sx={{ maxWidth: 50, margin: '0 auto' }}>
```

Note `margin: '0 auto'` CSS. Works on your very helpful, code sandbox.

Comment: Not just on the center but it should be on the lines

Answer (score 0):

if you want it in the center, try this: align-items: center

```
<Stack justifyContent={"center"}>
  <Button variant="contained" color="primary" sx={{ maxWidth: 50 }}>
    Hello
  </Button>
</Stack>
```

rewrite:

```
<Stack alignItems={"center"}>
  <Button variant="contained" color="primary" sx={{ maxWidth: 50 }}>
    Hello
  </Button>
</Stack>
```

or you can keep both: `justifyContent, alignItems`

Comment: Not just on the center but it should be on the lines

Answer (score 0):

You can give the button a negative marginTop (mt shortly) value.

```
import { Stack, Card, CardContent, Typography, Button } from "@mui/material";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const bull = "*";
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Stack spacing={2}>
        <Card sx={{ minWidth: 275 }}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography
              sx={{ fontSize: 14 }}
              color="text.secondary"
              gutterBottom
            >
              Word of the Day
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="h5" component="div">
              be{bull}nev{bull}o{bull}lent
            </Typography>
            <Typography sx={{ mb: 1.5 }} color="text.secondary">
              adjective
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2">
              well meaning and kindly.
              <br />
              {'"a benevolent smile"'}
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Stack>
      <Stack justifyContent={"center"} alignItems={"center"}>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          sx={{ maxWidth: 50, mt: -2.5 }}
        >
          Hello
        </Button>
      </Stack>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Quick Preview: [image: Edit wonderful-haze-k28yiy]

Ref: [overlap buttons in div tag using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492946/overlap-buttons-in-div-tag-using-css)

Answer (score -1):

Just add `direction="row"` to the stack. If you want it on the bottom dotted line then you'll have to adjust padding on the root css to remove bottom padding. ie. change `padding: 3` to `paddingTop: 3, paddingX: 3,`